# Installation issue in ActiveMQ 5.8

Tags: activemq-classic

### I today tried to install Apache Active MQ 5.8 on Win XP. When I used the command activemq_install_dir\bin\activemq to start it, I got the following output:

```
H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin>activemq
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_80 H:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre
  Heap sizes: current=1013632k  free=991262k  max=1013632k
    JVM args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.c
onfig.file=logging.properties -Dactivemq.classpath=H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\
..\conf;H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\../conf;H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\../con
f; -Dactivemq.home=H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\.. -Dactivemq.base=H:\apache-act
ivemq-5.8.0\bin\.. -Dactivemq.conf=H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\..\conf -Dactive
mq.data=H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\..\data -Djava.io.tmpdir=H:\apache-activemq
-5.8.0\bin\..\data\tmp
Extensions classpath:
  [H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\..\lib,H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\..\lib\camel
,H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\..\lib\optional,H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\..\li
b\web,H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\..\lib\extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\..
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\..
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\..\conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: H:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\..\data
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
```

---

The output doesn't proceed past "Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml" .. what should I do? Why did it hang at Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml ? Any solution for it?

Comment: Windows XP, ActiveMQ 5.8 and Java 1.7 - are you doing a show box for the local IT-museum? Try using some newer versions. Anyway, checkout log4j.properties and increase log level to see some more info

Comment: How to increase the log level in log4j.properties file?

Comment: The default logging level in ActiveMQ is INFO. In my log4j.properties file it is set as such : " log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console, logfile ". Yet the output is not getting past the above mentioned line. What should be done?

Comment: Since the default logging level in ActiveMQ is INFO, so I should see those INFO statements after "Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml" in the output, but unfortunately, this isn't happening. Don't know why